# Getting couldn't parse YAML error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am developing a project in Ruby on Rails. I'm a beginner to ROR.

I want to display api_console for the web services that I have created.

For this I have created **api_console_description.yml** in **config** directory.

```
Admin:
  create_admin:
    http_method:  POST
    requires_user_auth: true
    param_names:
      - "email","type:string, required:true, length:140, regex:[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]"
      - "password"
      - "password_confirmation"
      - "user_name"
```

**config/application.rb** -

```
config.api_console_description = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "api_console_description.yml"))
```

**views/api_console/index.html.haml** -

```
%br
%br

%table{:height => 400, :width => "100%", :border => 1, :cellpadding => 5}
  %tr
    %td{:width => 350, :valign => "top" }

      = render_navigation do |primary|
        - @controller_descriptions.each do |controller_description|
          - controller_name = controller_description.name.downcase
          - primary.item controller_name.to_sym, controller_name, api_console_path({:controller_name => controller_name}) do |subnav|
            - controller_description.methods.each do |method|
              - method_name = method.name.downcase
              - subnav.item method_name.to_sym, method_name, api_console_path({:controller_name => controller_name, :method_name => method_name})

    %td{:valign => "top"}  
      - @http_method = @method_description.http_method
      %form{:method => @http_method, :action => @url}
        %button{:id => "submitButton"} #{@http_method}
        %label URL = #{@url}
        // Quick and dirty implementation of dynamic form generation.  This is only for internal use for now, so I'm not worried about elegance, extensibility, etc.
        %br
        - #Process remaining param_names generically
        - param_names.uniq.each do |param_name|
          - if !param_names_displayed.include?(param_name)
            %br
            %label
              %b 
                = "#{param_name.titlecase} (#{param_name})"
            %input{:type => "text", :name => "#{param_name}"}
            - param_names_displayed << param_name


      %br
      %textarea{:id => 'apiOutput', :readonly => 'true', :style => "position:relative;width:100%;height:360px;background-color:#cecece;overflow:scroll"}
%table
```

But here I'm getting the **'parse'** error at the rails server start -

```
 /config/api_console_description.yml):couldn't parse YAML at line 6 column 16 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:125:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:112:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:229:in `load_file'
```

But if I remove the line **,"type:string, required:true, length:140, regex:[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]"** from yml file then it works fine. But I want to implement the validation on the **api_console_description** , so I have to add **"type:string ...."** for the appropriate fields.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not put comma to there between "email" and "type:string, required:true, length:140, regex:[_A-Za-z0-9-+]". You can check [the right syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) and fix that.

For example this would work:

```
Admin:
  create_admin:
  http_method:  POST
  requires_user_auth: true
  param_names:
    - { email: "type:string, required:true, length:140, regex:[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]" }
    - "password"
    - "password_confirmation"
    - "user_name"
```

Comment: Thanks @Jozsef for your reply.
I'hv tried this but getting error - 
undefined method `titlecase' for #<Hash:0xa6a4dfc>
  app/views/api_console/index.html.haml:44:in `block in _app_views_api_console_index_html_haml___911476944_83946690'

Comment: You should change the parsing of YAML file, because `param_names` could be `Hash` now not just `String`. `String` has `titlecase` method, but `Hash` does not have. Or you should change the structure of YAML file.